# Inject VM to custom control in WPF using Unity

Tags: dependency-injection, binding, custom-controls, unity-container

I am building a WPF based application. I am using Unity to inject all the different dependencies in my application (defined in App.xaml.cs).
In my MainApplication window I have a pretty complex look-less custom control derived from Control(is has about ten more control integrated in it).
I would like to inject a VM into this custom control without coupling it to any other object in my application (except App.xaml.cs of course)

Injection to any WPF window in my application works well, but when I try injecting to the custom control I am facing to different situation:
 1. In case I am using 
container.RegisterInstance(container.Resolve);

The DI creates a dummy instance of MyCustomControl and injects the VM (using [Dependency] attribute). However this specific instance is not used when I use it in my XAML:

in which case it initializes a new MyCustomControl ignoring any dependencies.

1. In case I am using 
   container.RegisterType();

The MyCustomControl completely ignores the injection.

I realize I am probably doing something wrong (not just technically) and I am really trying to avoid coupling this control (which will obviously solve the issue).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best solution and found your question while looking for other options but, alas, here is the approach I used to at least get up and running.

I created a base UnityControl class that subclasses Control.  In the constructor, I use the ServiceLocator to get a reference to the container.  Then I call the BuildUp method to resolve any dependencies on the derived control class.  Any dependencies are implemented as read/write properties marked with the DependencyAttribute.

Here's what UnityControl looks like:

```
public abstract class UnityControl : Control
{
    protected UnityControl() : base()
    {
        Container = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IUnityContainer>();
        Container.BuildUp(this.GetType(), this);
    }

    protected IUnityContainer Container { get; private set; }
}
```